# android - facebook and twitter authentication. how to log into php web server from android application using facebook and twitter sdk

Tags: php, android, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

My project has two parts, php web server and Android mobile application. The mobile application posts data (thread topics) to the web server backend using implemented web service.
 User can also register from the android client app. I want to implement login with facebook feature to enable the user to login using facebook account AND POST from the android client. I implemented the android sdk integration and I can get the access token there. what I miss is how to make the android login to the web server using facebook.

Posting topics to the server requires user registration, does that mean I should register the user when login with facebook ? the normal registration fields contains user name and email. I think if I want to login with facebook I should modify the registration mechanism to exclude the username and enable only login with email.

What is the mechanism (in the server side) to implement this ? will it be the same with twitter ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can store the username when a person login with facebook/twitter. The username should be the `userid` assigned by facebook/twitter. Also keep a track by keeping a field in the database to distinguish the user registration type. Other fields such as email can be taken from user using an update profile screen

Comment: Thanks for your replay @SunilMishra. what about the password ?. Login to the web server requires password, If I got the username and email using facebook sdk and registered the user using them, user needs a password to login. in normal login with facebook scenarios, users don't enter passwords ?!

Comment: You should have a mechanism where the user authenticated on facebook/twitter can login to your server. Once you get the access token, you allow the user to enter your server. You can also read about oauth from here http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: any clarification or example for that mechanism, how it could be ? (without oauth)

Comment: What I would do is login with facebook/twitter and then check using a webservice if this is a valid/registered user. If not, I create a new  user with that userid. If the user is valid/registered, I allow him to enter into the system

Comment: Thanks so much. I implemented this. But how I can check if the data coming from android app in valid facebook or twitter user. I mean the client android app will communicate with facebook, brings the email and user after authentication and send this data back to me with no password. how will I make sure it valid user ? should I use the access token in this, if yes how will I do this ?